# pointer to a function needs ; after definition

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

```
void (*pf)(int i){
};
```

According to C++11 I don't need a trailing ';', but Dev-C++ not only throws a Warning - but an Error and breaks compiling.

But if I'd declare

```
void pf(int i){
}
```

no warning is thrown anymore?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two things you've shown are vastly different.

```
void (*pf)(int i){
};
```

The above defines `pf` as a *pointer to a function* taking an `int` and returning `void`, and values initializes it. The semi-colon is **required**. It's the same as

```
void (*pf)(int i) = nullptr;
```

In the second snippet

```
void pf(int i){
}
```

`pf` is a *function* taking an `int` and returning `void`.

I'm guessing your version of Dev-C++ doesn't support C++11's uniform initialization syntax. The following should work

```
void (*pf)(int i) = NULL;
```

Answer (score 3):

Would you write the following? (Missing semicolon.)

```
int* p
```

No, a semicolon is needed at the end of a variable declaration.

What you're trying to do is equivalent:

```
void (*pf)(int i)
```

This a variable declaration for `pf` which is a pointer to a function with signature `(int) -> void` and thus it requires a semicolon at the end of the line. It is a function *pointer* declaration, not a function declaration.

The following is a function declaration, which does not require a semicolon at the end:

```
void pf(int i) {
}
```